# Dymola-Simulink interface

Tags: matlab, simulink, dymola

I'm trying to create a compound model of Matlab and Dymola. Therefore I followed this tutorial: [Claytex tutorial](https://www.claytex.com/blog/dymola-simulink-interface/)

Instead of the DrivenPendulum model, I made a simple model myself. I can translate the model in Dymola just fine, and the Compilation of the Dymola model in Matlab works like in the tutorial, too. But as soon as I try to simulate in Simulink I receive the following error message:

Error evaluating 'InitFcn' callback of SubSystem block (mask) 'test/DymolaBlock/compmodel'. Block test/DymolaBlock is not up to date. Please recompile it!

Recompiling obviously doesn't work, I get this message again and again.

I'm using Dymola 2019 Matlab R2018b with MinGW GCCx64 Compiler.

But maybe someone of you has an idea or even encountered this problem already?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a Visual Studio C compiler.

This is what the Dymola User Manual Volume 2 says about the Matlab/Simulink interface in chapter 6.2:

> The Dymola – Simulink interface of Dymola 2019 supports Matlab
>   releases from R2013a (version 8.1) up to R2017b (version 9.3). Only
>   Visual Studio C++ compilers are supported to generate the DymolaBlock
>   S-function on Windows. For Linux the gcc compiler is supported. The
>   LCC compiler is not supported, neither on Windows nor Linux.

Comment: Thanks for help, i installed a Visual studio C compiler ( Visual Studio 2017/ Visual C++ Express edition) and recompile the Dymola block in Simulink with the new compiler, but the error isn't changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you select this compiler also in Matlab? From the Claytex tutorial: "To do this type mex -setup at the Matlab command line and select a Microsoft Visual C++ compiler"